# why my bootstrap template have different view in Chrome & Mozilla?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, google-chrome

my bootstrap template have a different view in Chrome - Mozilla & IE !
my resolution is 1920 * 1080 (Asus N56j) 
screen shot in Chrome:
[image: screen shot in Chrome:]

screen shot in Mozilla:

[image: screen shot in Mozilla]

I've added the following code in head:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

my Mozilla & Chrome & IE zoom is 100% but different view.
Live Demo: http://saghian.ir/iastjd/

Comment: Pretty sure you just zoomed out on Chrome. Try CTRL-0 (zero).

Comment: please do not use the "bootstrap" tag. mouse over it and you will see it doesn't relate to web development

Comment: Dear @Siguza I understand you, zoom in 100% but don't change view!
do u have idea ?

Comment: Not really, unless you're zoomed *in* in Firefox... maybe I should also state that I'm unable to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Siguza; i watch this page in old laptop (resolution 1366), same Mozilla in resolution 1920.